# Recycle drawable of Imagebutton

Tags: android

In my 'homescreen' fragment I have a couple of Imagebuttons. XML for the Imagebutton is:

```
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/merkzettel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/dashboard_merkzettel_icon__selector" />
```

And the drawable XML selector looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_startseite_merkzettel_on"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_startseite_merkzettel_off" />
</selector>
```

On an older device (Nexus S) when I flip the the device around for a while (changing screen orientation) I get the exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
etcetc
```

This seems to be a common problem beause Android recreated the bitmap drawable every time the Activity / Fragment is recreated and for Drawables the recommended solution is to `drawable.recycle()` them in `onDestroy()` but I can't find a suitable method to get a hold on the drawable of the ImageButton.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: In manifest file's application tag add android:largeHeap = "true" then run your project.

Comment: How big are your images? You're probably already at the peek of your memory usage.

Comment: I'd look for memory leaks elsewhere

Comment: @gunar One PNG is about 4kb, so they're pretty small.

Comment: @FunkTheMonk I don't quite get what you mean, the LogCat is pretty clear that this has to do with the Bitmaps right?

Comment: It is loading the bitmaps that cause you to go over your memory limit - but why? Every time you rotate, android is creating a new instance of your Activity - if you retain a reference to the old instances of the activity, eventually it will bust your memory limit.

Comment: Then you're at the peak of your memory usage. Use some memory profiling tools for that. Ex: Memory Analyzer Tool plugin for Eclipse

Comment: Okay, I've read up on some of the memory leaks stuff on SO and Google and it looks like I'm pretty carelessly tossing around activities / avtivity-context. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

In manifest file's application tag add android:largeHeap = "true" then run your project.

Like Below

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
    android:largeHeap="true">
<application/>
```

In Destroy method

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ((BitmapDrawable)imagebutton.getDrawable()).getBitmap.recycle();
}
```

and in onCreate method check this.

```
if (imagebutton.getDrawable() == null){
  // set your image button image here.
} else {
  // nothing to do.
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's an appropiate solution. My app is a lightweight app and shouldn't need a large heap. Also, this is available in API lvl 11, i have a min lvl of 8.

Comment: Then in onDestroy method recycle the bitmap and wherever you are setting imagebutton image check this condition in my answer.

Comment: As to your Edit: You're casting an ImageButton to a BitmapDrawable there, that doesn't work. Are you sure this works for you?

Comment: ((BitmapDrawable)imagebutton.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle(); use this line for getting drawable to recycle